# how to orginize words in a variable verticly using bash?

Tags: linux, bash

so basicly i have this variable that includes some names for example :

```
help1= first second
```

now i want to to take every word in this variable and orginize them in an array 
this is what i have tried so far , it is not working because i thought the words were orginized verticly in the help1 variable , i want to know how can i orginize the words vertically in help1 or if there is another way to solve my problem.
this is what i tried already :

```
rooms_array=(1)                 ## help1 include sorted room names
help1="`ls -l | tail -n+2 | sort -r | grep ^d | cut -d" " -f9 | sort`"   #####intilize array for rooms
for ((j=0 ; j<$rooms_num ;j++ )); do
x="`head -n+1 help1`"   
rooms_array[j]=$x
help2="`tail -n+2 help1`"
help1="$help2"
done
```

Comment: State what is your requirement is, than explain why your solution didn't work, I am sure there are lot of ways to simplify the number of commands you are using

Comment: Try: `echo "$help1" | tr ' ' '\n'`

Comment: ok i am sorry i am gonna write my question exactly and what i tried

Answer (score 0):

```
cat help1

first second
```

maybe in `awk`

```
awk ' { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
      { print $i }
} ' help1
first
second
```

Comment: i don't think this will help :\ i want the the words to be orginized virticaly ! but thank you anyway :))

Comment: thank you i fixed the code at the end by only adding " " to help 1 but i tried what you suggested it didn't work :| but thank you anyway for trieng to help me :))